# Where does nginx expect to find its modules?

Tags: nginx

Where does [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) expect to find the binary files for its modules?  For example, by convention, where should I install module [`nginx_ajp_module`](https://github.com/yaoweibin/nginx_ajp_module)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The module path will vary depending on the Linux distribution you're using. Some distros (e.g. Debian-based) may put it in strange places.

To find the module path on your system, run `nginx -V` and look for the `--modules-path` in the output. For example:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.10.1
built by gcc 6.1.1 20160510 (Red Hat 6.1.1-2) (GCC) 
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2h-fips  3 May 2016 (running with OpenSSL 1.0.2j-fips  26 Sep 2016)
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib64/nginx/modules ...
```

You should also be aware that dynamic module loading was only introduced in the 1.10 development cycle. Modules older than this were designed to be compiled directly into nginx, and would need to be updated for dynamic loading. The module you linked to is such a one. Contact its developer for further information.

Comment: On my Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 system, `nginx -V` doesn't include `--modules-path`.

Comment: @DerekMahar You'll have to take that up with Canonical. I personally avoid Ubuntu for anything important.

Answer (score 10):

`nginx -V` will only reveal the `--modules-path` config flag if nginx was configured with an explicit `--modules-path` argument. (I.e., if you ran `./configure --modules-path=/path/to/modules` when compiling nginx, you'd see `--modules-path=/path/to/modules` in the output of `nginx -V`.) The default location, if no path was specified at compile time, is `$NGX_PREFIX/modules`. On my macOS system, `$NGX_PREFIX` defaults to `/usr/local/nginx`, so the default modules path is `/usr/local/nginx/modules`; whereas Ubuntu 17.10 breaks the prefixed monolith up a bit and expects modules in `/usr/lib/nginx/modules`.

As with many *nix-adjacent things, configuration is privileged over convention here. You may find that your best bet is to compile nginx on your own, specifying the `--prefix=` and/oror `--modules-path=` flags when running `./configure`. There are some good docs on that process [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-open-source/#sources) and [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-compile-nginx-from-source-on-a-centos-6-4-x64-vps).

Comment: You can also specify the prefix at runtime using the `-p` flag for `nginx`. See https://github.com/openresty/openresty/issues/180#issuecomment-228846735